# How can you safely add a dependency to a Drupal module?

Tags: drupal-6

I have a new version of a Drupal 6 module. In the new version, I have added a new dependency in the .info file to a views utility module I've created called lib_views.

However, lib_views may not be enabled when my module is upgraded. If it's not, then upgrading my module causes an irretrievable crash, because views fires a hook that invokes a function in my un-enabled lib_views module.

Is there any safe way to add a new dependency to an existing Drupal module that can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force drupal to load the module (it's common practice for CCK modules for example).

Example:

```
function example_install() {
    drupal_load('module', 'content');
    content_notify('install', 'example');
}
```

In the example, `drupal_load` loads the "*content*" module first, then `content_notify` is an example of function that can only be used when the content module is available.

So if the `drupal_load` call returns `FALSE`, you can detect that the module is missing and notify the user.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 handles this automatically when going to update.php (which you are suppose to visit after updating a module). I suppose another alternative would be to display a warning message via an update function.

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion? For me this didn't "just work".